# In app purchases - recover subscribed users in a new app

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

We already have an app on Google Play with in app purchases (as subscriptions), and there are lots of users who already purchased our subscriptions. However, we have developed a new version of this app from scratch and we want to list it on Google Play as a new app. After few months, we want to unpublish the old version of it. There is one issue with this: How do we make sure that users who already purchased subscriptions in the old app keep their subscriptions in the new one? It seems like there is no way around this other than asking them to purchase on the new one. But maybe there is a better idea than that?

P.S. We are publishing as totally new listing because of significant changes in the app and also the old one wasn't taken care of properly, therefore there were many bad ratings. This would be a fresh start.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe , there is a way.

From Your Old App Obtain 2 things

1. GOOGLE API KEY FOR IN APP PURCHASE
2. product id (is unique everytime)

Inside the java code, check all the purchase history for this particular product from Billing object.

This library is excellent in simplyfing in-app purchases.

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Comment: But the user still has to do the purchase on the new app, as far as I understand. Because the app cannot do it on its own. The best the app can do it to suggest that they can purchase in the new app since they already had purchased in the old one, or am I wrong?

Comment: you can fetch whether they had purchased earlier and then set your preferences for that user accordingly

Comment: That would work if it was a one time purchase product. In my case, it is a recurring subscription. It would work as long as the old app remains. But the old app will be removed after some time, and their subscription won't be updated unless they make a new subscription on the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to tell the play store that the user has bought a subscription for the new app.  You could update the old app to send subscription data to a server which can mark the user as having bought a subscription, and then the server can validate the new app to deliver subscription content. But the play store will not know anything about it.